# Can Sequelize sum, count, group by or should I use sequelize.query option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Can Sequelize sum, count, group by or should I use sequelize.query option?

```
select count(col1), sum(col2) from my_table
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [
       [db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.col('col1'), 'col1')],
       [db.sequelize.fn('sum', db.sequelize.col('col2'), 'col2')]
  ],
  group: ['col1']
});
```